# Keep text from wrapping around floated image

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

I currently have an image that is floating left, and a block of text that rests to the right of it. That block of text is not current floated, it just comes after the image in the HTML. So as it gets longer it eventually kicks over to the left under the image to continue on.

How can I make it so the block of text always stays to the right of the image, so the image and the text behave like two side-by-side columns? Bear in  mind that I cannot do anything outside of these two elements. I cannot add a wrapper around them. I can add elements before, between, or after. But not around.

Thanks.

Comment: Code samples, code samples, code samples!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JtdsH/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIXED ANSWER**

Just float the text as well. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Hs7pN/

```
#image
{
    background-color: #09C;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

#text
{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p
{
width:1000px;
display: table-row;       
}
```

Comment: I don't actually recommend this. It will not work on some older browsers, and can provide unexpected results depending on other elements.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett Will it work on IE7 and up? I actually like the css-table approach, and I am seeing it more and more. But I need support for IE7+.

Comment: That kills that option. :-( I need IE7 support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting fixed width if possible and Justify your text